# How can I import module in project?

Tags: python, intellij-idea, pythonpath

I have a package `ipin.crawler.base.common` in my project, I want to import this module in file as follow:

```
from ipin.crawler.base.common import CommonConfig
```

I run the file in `Intellij IDEA`, it is ok, but I run file in `bash`, it raise `ImportError: No module named crawler.base.common`.

I observered that `Intellij IDEA` `add source roots to PYTHONPATH`, so how can I run file in bash?

Comment: have you tried `export PYTHONPATH=path/of/ipin`?

Comment: @sirfz yes, I have tried, `PYTHONPATH=/Users/roger/python/base_crawler_py`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, that is my fault, I should use

```
export PYTHONPATH=/Users/roger/python/base_crawler_py
```

instead of

```
PYTHONPATH=/Users/roger/python/base_crawler_py
```